# format the date like 12:30 PM 12TH JANUARY 2000 in javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have to display the date in jsp 12:30 PM 12TH JANUARY 2000  in this format .How can i format the current date in the above format in JavaScript or using jQuery UI.

```
var currentDate = new Date();
currentDate.toString("hh:MM dS MMMM yyyy")
```

I have tried the above code but it's not working.

Comment: i have tried this var currentDate = new Date();currentDate.toString("hh:MM dS MMMM yyyy").but itz not working

Comment: Add your comment in edit of u'r question

Comment: This has been asked and answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1056728.

Answer (score 0):

jquery date format is separate plugin.U need to add explicitly using `<script>` tag.

Formatting using javascript

```
<script>
    $.format.date("2009-12-18 10:54:50.546", "dd/MM/yyyy");
    </script>
```

E.g.,

```
<script>
document.write($.format.date("2009-12-18 10:54:50.546", "Test: dd/MM/yyyy"));
document.write($.format.date("Wed Jan 13 10:43:41 CET 2010", "dd~MM~yyyy"));
</script>
```

See [here](https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat)

Answer (score 0):

Strange as it seems, Javascript doesn't have a built-in function or method that lets you specify the date/time formatting.

But you can use something like this: https://github.com/samsonjs/strftime